# Where should I go if I want to become a saint?

Tags: catholicism, saint

From Wikipedia (article "Saint"):

> The Catholic Church teaches that it does not "make" or "create" saints, but rather recognizes them. Proofs of heroic virtue required in the process of beatification will serve to illustrate in detail the general principles exposed above upon proof of their holiness or likeness to God.

Because the Church is not in the business of making saints, where do Catholics recommend a sinner to go in order to become a Saint?

Comment: The church *is* in the business of making saints! It doesn't do it by canonization -- that's the recognizing part -- but by bringing us to Christ, and closer to Christ.  One part that differs from Protestantism (mostly) is the church says do the sacraments, starting with baptism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Where should I go if I want to become a saint?**

*Because the Church is not in the business of making saints, where do Catholics recommend a sinner to go in order to become a Saint?*

If one desires to be a saint with a capital **”S”**, then one must live a life of holiness and have practiced a lifestyle of heroic virtues. In the case of repented sinners a length of ten years in generally long enough to be considered as a candidate for beatification and canonization by Rome. The real short cut would also be in being declared a martyr. A few sinners, under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit were able to become witnesses of Christ through martyrdom.

> The notion of heroicity is derived from hero, originally a warrior, a demigod; hence it connotes a degree of bravery, fame, and distinction which places a man high above his fellows. St. Augustine first applied the pagan title of hero to the Christian martyrs; since then the custom has prevailed of bestowing it not only on martyrs, but on all confessors whose virtues and good works greatly outdistance those of ordinary good people. Benedict XIV, whose chapters on heroic virtue are classical, thus describes heroicity: "In order to be heroic a Christian virtue must enable its owner to perform virtuous actions with uncommon promptitude, ease, and pleasure, from supernatural motives and without human reasoning, with self-abnegation and full control over his natural inclinations." An heroic virtue, then, is a habit of good conduct that has become a second nature, a new motive power stronger than all corresponding inborn inclinations, capable of rendering easy a series of acts each of which, for the ordinary man, would be beset with very great, if not insurmountable, difficulties.
>
> Such a degree of virtue belongs only to souls already purified from all attachment to things worldly, and solidly anchored in the love of God. St. Thomas (I-II:61:4) says:
>
> > Virtue consists in the following, or imitation, of God. Every virtue, like every other thing, has its type [exemplar] in God. Thus the Divine mind itself is the type of prudence; God using all things to minister to His glory is the type of temperance, by which man subjects his lower appetites to reason; justice is typified by God's application of the eternal law to all His works; Divine immutability is the type of fortitude. And, since it is man's nature to live in society, the four cardinal virtues are social [politicae] virtues, inasmuch as by them man rightly ordains his conduct in daily life. Man, however, must raise himself beyond his natural life unto a life Divine: 'Be you therefore perfect, as also your heavenly Father is perfect' (Matthew 5:48). It is, therefore, necessary to posit certain virtues midway between the social virtues, which are human, and the exemplary virtues, which are Divine. These intermediate virtues are of two degrees of perfection: the lesser in the soul still struggling upwards from a life of sin to a likeness with God — these are called purifying virtues [virtutes purgatoriae]; the greater in the souls which have already attained to the Divine likeness — these are called virtues of the purified soul [virtutes jam purgati animi]. In the lesser degree, prudence, moved by the contemplation of things Divine, despises all things earthly and directs all the soul's thought unto God alone; temperance relinquishes, as far as nature allows, the things required for bodily wants; fortitude removes the fear of departing this life and facing the life beyond; justice approves of the aforesaid dispositions. In the higher perfection of souls already purified and firmly united with God, prudence knows nothing but what it beholds in God; temperance ignores earthly desires; fortitude knows nothing of passions; justice is bound to the Divine mind by a perpetual compact to do as it does. This degree of perfection belongs to the blessed in heaven or to a few of the most perfect in this life.
>
> These few perfectissimi are the heroes of virtue, the candidates for the honours of the altar, the saints on earth.
>
> Together with the four cardinal virtues the Christian saint must be endowed with the three theological virtues, especially with Divine charity, the virtue which informs, baptizes, and consecrates, as it were, all other virtues; which associates and unifies them into one powerful effort to participate in the Divine life. Some remarks on the "proofs of heroicity" required in the process of beatification will serve to illustrate in detail the general principles exposed above.
>
> As charity stands at the summit of all virtues, so faith stands at their foundation. For by faith God is first apprehended, and the soul lifted up to supernatural life. Faith is the secret of one's conscience; to the world it is made manifest by the good works in which it lives, "Faith without works is dead" (James 2:2). Such works are: the external profession of faith, strict observance of the Divine commands, prayer, filial devotion to the Church, the fear of God, the horror of sin, penance for sins committed, patience in adversity, etc. All or any of these attain the grade of heroicity when practiced with unflagging perseverance, during a long period of time, or under circumstances so trying that by them men of but ordinary perfection would be deterred from acting. Martyrs dying in torments for the Faith, missionaries spending their lives in propagating it, the humble poor who with infinite patience drag out their wretched existence to do the will of God and to reap their reward hereafter, these are heroes of the Faith. - [Heroic Virtue](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07292c.htm)

I remember a talk of Pope St. John Paul II to young people and he asked them to make themselves saint and to do it quickly. Whether the Church recognizes all the saints is immaterial. Remember that there exists the Feast of All Saints for the honour of all the Saints who names are known to God alone and those already in heaven.

Answer (score 1):

The supreme law or goal of the Catholic Church is the salvation of souls:

> [Can. 1752](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib7-cann1732-1752_en.html#CHAPTER_II.) […] the salvation of souls, which must always be the supreme law in the Church, is to be kept before one’s eyes.

Thus, the Church indeed does make saints.